# Return only returning 1st item

Tags: python, list, return

In my function below I'm trying to return the full text from multiple .txt files and append the results to a list, however, my function only returns the text from the first file in my directory. That said if I replace return with print it logs all the results to the console on its own line but I can't seem to append the results to a list. What am I doing wrong with the return function.
Thanks.

```
import glob
import copy

file_paths = []
file_paths.extend(glob.glob("C:\Users\7812397\PycharmProjects\Sequence      diagrams\*"))
matching_txt = [s for s in file_paths if ".txt" in s]
full_text = []
def fulltext():
    for file in matching_txt:
        f = open(file, "r")
        ftext = f.read()
        all_seqs = ftext.split("title ")
        return all_seqs
print fulltext()
```

Comment: fix your indentation in your function (return  is inside loop)

Answer (score 0):

You're putting `return` inside your loop. I think you want to do. Although, you could yield the values here.

```
for file in matching_txt:
    f = open(file, "r")
    ....
    full_text.append(all_seqs)
return full_text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your function to a generator which is more efficient in terms of memory use:

```
def fulltext():
    for file_name in matching_txt:
        with open(file_name) as f:
            ftext = f.read()
            all_seqs = ftext.split("title ")
            yield all_seqs
```

Then convert the generator to a list if they are not huge, other wise you can simply loop over the result if you want to use the generator's items:

```
full_text = list(fulltext())
```

Some issues in your function:

First off, don't use python built-in names as variable names (in this case file).
Secondly for dealing with files (and other internal connections) you better to use `with` statement which will close the file at the end of the block automatically.